# Excel VBA - Get a Cells value by using Offset, based on the data from another column

Tags: vba, excel

Column K can contain the string 'Item Cost'.  When Column K contains 'Item Cost' I would like to offset to Column U and copy the value from that cell within the same ROW as the string 'Item Cost'.

I can get the code to read and find the value in Column K, but am having a problem with the coping portion of the code for Column U.

```
Dim range1 As Range
Dim Answer4 As Variant
LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


For Each range1 In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("K9:K" & LstRw)
  If range1.Offset(0, 0) = "Item Cost " Then
        'MsgBox "found"
         Answer4 = range1.Offset(0, 10).Value  '<---- PROBLEM
  End If
Next

'Msgbox Answer4 'returns nothing

 wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10").Value = Answer4  'returns nothing
```

Comment: K offset to U is `10` not `8`

Comment: `range1.Offset(0, 0)` the offset is not needed.

Comment: That was embarassing.  Yes, it is 10 not 8, I had two columns hidden.  That said- updating the existing code to '10' did not impact the progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you will want to make your destination range dynamic (`Range("D10")`). The code as is will continousely re-write over your value in `D10`. Do you maybe want the value to be in Col D on the same row as the target range? If so, swap

```
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") = range1.Offset(0, 10)
```

for

```
wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & range1.Row) = range1.Offset(0, 10)
```

---

```
For Each range1 In wbFrom.Sheets("Sheet0").Range("K9:K" & LstRw)
  If range1 = "Item Cost " Then
        'MsgBox "found"
         wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") = range1.Offset(0, 10) 
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @Urdearboy and Scott.  Your first suggestion was correct, with the  `wbTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") = range1.Offset(0, 10)`

Comment: Your comment was so confusing at first. My name is also Scott and I was thinking **HOW DID HE KNOW**

Comment: :D  Funny stuff.